# Regex to remove commas from numbers under 10,000

Tags: regex, number-formatting

I need a single regex to strip commas from all numbers under 10,000, e.g., 9999 but 10,000, 1,000,000, etc.

This works fine for 9,999, correctly ignores 10,000, but screws up 1,000,000 (1000,000):

```
\b([0-9]),([0-9]{3}) 
$1$2
```

I can't simply rule out a comma after a 4-digit number like 9999, unfortunately. I tried another approach, but it misses 9,999:

```
\b(?<![.,])(?<d1>\d{2})(?<d2>\d{3})(?!,)\b
$1,$2
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Randy

UPDATE: Sorry, I forgot to mention this must work in .NET, so \K won't work...

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Better mach digits and compare them programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this must work in .NET, so \K won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match numbers under 10,000, you could match a single digit before the comma instead of 2, and match 1-3 digits after the comma to also match 1,9 for example.

To prevent a partial match, you could assert whitespace boundaries.

```
(?<!\S)(?<d1>\d),(?<d2>\d{1,3})(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N13PBA/1)

Comment: Upvoted but it wouldnt strip commas from any position but a possible last position when I tested it. You focused on the second position for the comma?

Comment: @JvdV I assumed the OP meant values from 0,0 to 9,999. Maybe I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this matches "1,9" which won't work. I have scientific papers that often use references exactly like this.

Comment: @Randy You could match 3 digits instead of 1-3 `(?<!\S)(?<d1>\d),(?<d2>\d{3})(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/a3YWFr/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Thank you very much! Works great! I am learning a lot a bout regex here! I also have to ensure everything also HAS the right commas, i.e., 
1000000

Comment: @Randy Do you mean `1000000` should become `1,000,000`? If so, you could first match all the numbers  `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/4XAPIL/1 and then use this pattern `(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\S))` and replace with a comma https://regex101.com/r/q4q7Ns/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Thanks again... Work great, but this also gets 9999, which was my orignal issue. Of course, I suppose I could run them sequentially, but with lots of replaces I'm not sure that would work every time.

Comment: You could use a quantifier like 7 or more `{7,}` to specify how many digits you want to match first `(?<!\S)\d{7,}(?!\S)`https://regex101.com/r/ia9xyD/1

Comment: @The fourth bird Not quite working for me yet. I have to step out for a sec. Will come back in a couple. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents:

```
(?:^(?=(?:,*\d,*){1,4}$)|\G(?!^))\d*\K,(?!$)
```

See the online [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sh0Q6c/6)

My idea was to remove any comma no matter where in the string, e.g.: `,,,8`, `9,,,9` etc, as long as there are only up to 4 digits.

Comment: Ah I see that you mean :-) I thought the comma's after the digits in the question where punctuation marks.  In that case +1 (not that \G and \K are not supported in all engines)

Comment: You might be right yourself. Anyways, I hope I implemented these correctly. I learned this through your posts bytw ;) @Thefourthbird

Comment: I think you have to use `\G(?!^)` See this [example](https://regex101.com/r/Ut85nT/1) vs this [example](https://regex101.com/r/JlWF3W/1) If the assertion for 4 digits fails, it will evaluate the OR `|`, which is true because `\G` matches at 2 positions. Then it will start the match. Using `\G(?!^)` will prevent that.

Comment: Great, I'll keep that in mind! Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts guys! Sorry, I forgot to mention this must work in .NET, so it looks like \K won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply insert ***[0-9]{1-3}*** after your regex expression:

```
\b([0-9]),([0-9]{3})(,[0-9]{1-3})
```

or something like:

```
\d+((,)\d+)
```

would also work.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I couldn't get this to work for me